# First paragraph in environment without indent or space

Tags: spacing, environments

I'm trying to create an environment that does not indent the very first paragraph of the text inside the environment.

My latest attempt and the corresponding output are shown below. As you can see, the first environment added some small horizontal space to the first non-indented paragraph. The second environment did not, but I could only achieve this by adding a `%` character after `\begin{env}`, which should not be needed. How can I omit this unwanted space without an explicit `%` character?

[image: Result of minimal example]

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\newenvironment{env}{%
    \noindent%
}{%
}%

\begin{document}
Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.
Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.
Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.

\begin{env}
    First paragraph inside environment.

    Second paragraph inside environment.
\end{env}

\begin{env}%
    First paragraph inside environment.

    Second paragraph inside environment.
\end{env}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `ignorespaces`

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{env}{%
\noindent\ignorespaces%
}{%
}%

\begin{document}
Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.
Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.
Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.

\begin{env}
    First paragraph inside environment.

    Second paragraph inside environment.
\end{env}

\begin{env}%
    First paragraph inside environment.

    Second paragraph inside environment.
\end{env}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd add `\par` before `\noindent`. Why is the space (precisely the end-of-line after `\begin{env}`) not ignored? Because `\noindent` starts paragraph mode.

Comment: What is the role of the `%` symbol here? To comment-out the line break in the source code?